# Sudden fps drop during multi-touch

Tags: wpf, touch

I have a `WPF` application showing a large image (1024x1024) inside a [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas.aspx). On top of the image, I have some 400 ellipses. I'm handling touch events by setting `IsManipulationEnabled="True"` and handling the `ManipulationDelta` event. This works perfectly when zooming slowly. But as soon as I start **zooming quickly**, there is a **sudden frame-rate drop** resulting in a very jumpy zoom. I can hear the `CPU` fan speeding up when this occurs. Here are some screenshots from the `WPF Performance Suite` at the time when the frame-rate drops:

**Perforator**

[image: Perforator]

**Visual Profiler**

[image: Visual Profiler]

### Software renderer kicks in?

I'm not sure how to interpret these values, but I would guess that the graphics driver is overwhelmed by the amount of graphics to render, causing the `CPU` to take over some of the job. When zooming using touch, the scale changes by small fractions. Maye this has something to do with it?

So far, I have tried a number of optimization tricks, but none seem to work. The only thing that seems to work is to lower the number of ellipses to around 100. That gives acceptable performance.

Certainly this is a common problem for zoomable applications. **What can I do to avoid this sudden frame-rate drop?**

### UPDATE

I discovered that `e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X` is set to `3.0..` in the `ManipulationDelta` event. Usually, it is around `1.01..`. Why this sudden jump?

### UPDATE 2

**This problem is definitely linked to multi-touch.** As soon as I use more than one finger, there is a huge performance hit. My guess is that the touch events flood the message queue. See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/903760/wpf-touch-services-are-badly-broken) and [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782456/wpf-touch-event-fires-with-delay) report at Microsoft Connect. It seems the sequence `Touch event` -> `Update bound value` -> `Render` yields this performance problem. Obviously, this is a common problem and a solution is nowhere to be found.

`WPF` gurus out there, can you please show how to write a high performance multi-touch `WPF` application!

Comment: The ellipses are zoomed with the image?

Comment: Yes, the ellipses are zoomed with the image. Hence, they must be re-rendered.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet. Though, I'm starting to suspect that certain offsets cause the pixel snapping to malfunction, which in turn would cause some interpolation. E.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx

Comment: is it possible for you to upload a working sample of your app which can reproduce the issue you are facing? I would prefer to have a look on the implementation. I have done some optimizations is past, may I find something to squeeze in some more frames.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you've just reached the limits of WPF. The problem with WPF is that it tesselates (on CPU) vertex grafics each time it is rendered. Probably to reduce video memory usage. So you can imagine what happens when you place 600 ellipses.

If the ellipses are not resized then you could try to use `BitmapCache` option. In this way ellipses will be randered just once in the begining and then will be stored as textures. This will increase memory usage but should be ok I think.

If your ellipses are resized then previous technic won't work as each ellips will be rerendered when resized and and it will be even slower as this will rewrite textures (HW IRTs in perforator).

Another possibility is to design special control that will use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render ellipses to bitmaps and then will render it through Image control. In this way you can control when to render ellipses you could even render them in parralel threads (don't forget about STA). For example you can update ellipse bitmaps only when user interaction ends.

You can read [this article](http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/) about WPF rendering. I don't agree with the author who compares WPF with iOS and Android (both use mainly bitmaps compared to WPF). But it gives a good explanation about how WPF performs rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. What I don't understand is that my application performs well except for this "stuttering" that occurs when zooming fast. It's like the renderer is paused for half a second, then it works as expected again. This usually happens around a zoom factor of 2.0.

Comment: Did you test your solution without touch input? Hooking scale to mousewheel or by animating the scale? Some touch drivers (for exemple some 3M) may overflood windows event stack and cause some slow down.

Comment: Mousewheel works perfectly (coalesced messages?) and animating the scale also shows much better performance. You're on to something! Any workarounds? I'm using an Acer S7.

Comment: Not sure why this happens. Try to disable Windows touch shortcuts. You could also check whether this happens when using Input simulator from Surface SDK 2.0.

Comment: I think WPF only invalidates the triangulated geometry once you cross a certain size difference threshold.  I vaguely recall that being 2X, which would support the notion that re-tessellation happens when you hit a zoom factor of 2.0.